# Count unique string occurences in each colum and print results by colum

Tags: string, sum, unique

I have a text file with about 20 million rows and 100 columns. I would like to output a summary statistic of the number of occurences of each string in each column. Here is a portion of the file including the header which is the sample names.

```
 LP605  LP606   LP607   LP608   LP609
0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
0/0 1/1 1/1 0/0 0/0
0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0
0/1 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/0
1/1 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0
1/1 1/1 ./. 0/0 ./.
0/0 0/0 ./. 0/0 ./.
0/1 0/1 0/0 0/0 0/1
```

Desired output of summary statistics

```
Summary LP605   LP606   LP607   LP608   LP609
0/0 4   4   8   8   6
0/1 2   2   1   1   1
1/1 2   1   1   0   0
./. 0   2   2   0   2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick, using awk

```
  NR==31 {                  # File header is on line 31
    print "GT", $0          # Print "GT" followed by header
    n=NF                    # Record the number of columns
    next                    # Stop processing
  }
  {                         # For every line
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {  # & for every column ("i")
      A[i,$i]++             # Use an array A to store the the number of occurrences of the value ($i) in column i
      V[$i]                 # Record all values of ($i)
    }
  } END {
    for(j in V) {           # For all values of ($i)
      $1=j                  # Assign the value to field 1
      for(i=1; i<=n; i++)   # For all columns            
        $(i+1)=A[i,j]+0     # Assign the number of occurrences of value "j" to the appropriate column
      print                 # Print the line
    }
  } 
  OFS='\t' file             # Use tab output field separator
```